# Specs2 and scalacheck - must pass issue

Tags: scala, specs2, scalacheck

I get `not found: value pass` error for the code snippet below.
Do I miss any import or this code is not valid for *specs2* ?

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.ScalaCheck
import org.scalacheck.{Prop, Gen}

class TestSpec extends Specification with ScalaCheck {
  "Calling test spec" should {
    "always pass" in {  
      val prop = Prop.forAll((a:Int) => true)
      prop must pass
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`must pass` is something which was used in the original [specs](https://code.google.com/p/specs/) project. With specs2 you can simply write:

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.ScalaCheck
import org.scalacheck.{Prop, Gen}

class TestSpec extends Specification with ScalaCheck {
  "Calling test spec" should {
    "always pass" in prop { (a:Int) => 
      true
    }
    "with a custom generator" in {
      Prop.forAll(smallInteger) { i: Int =>
        true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where should I put my generator `Prop.forAll` ?

Comment: The body of the `in` method accepts any valid ScalaCheck property so you can use the standard ScalaCheck syntax for declaring properties using custom generators.